# Flex setStyle("modalTransparencyColor", color) bug, issues with variations of hexadecimal color code

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I have an issue working with the setStyle() on the modalTransprancyColor property.  The module did not run on different variations of hexadecimal code, only one that seems to work is 0xDDDDDD. Anything else, this line of code will crash Flash.

```
Application.application.setStyle('modalTransparencyColor', '0xDDDDDD');
        PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
```

Tried: 'black', '0xff0000', '0xFF0000', '0x0116FC'

I'm using Flex 3.6v16995 with Flash Builder 4

Comment: I think it is not a problem from setStyle, and 0xDDDDDD is default color. where you add above code? can you give more details about your application?

Comment: First, why are you doing `Application.application`? It's a horrible practice.  Why aren't you using CSS on the main app mxml?

Comment: I'm new working with flex and this is a code from another developer, I'm working on the bug fixes. The code is in an as file that manages the popup that generates a survey data flow.  This particular code is the only implementation in the function surveyPopupClose() @JAX Could you explain why it's bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

From my tests, setting the `modal-transparency-color` CSS in the Application does not cascade down into the pop up, and only the style in the pop up class itself determines what is used.

Try setting the style from within the Class that is being popped up as a modal window.

Example:

```
<!-- componenets/MyPopUp.mxml -->
<s:TitleWindow ... styleName="myColor">
  <fx:Style>
    .myColor {
      modal-transparency-color: '0xff0000';
    }
  </fx:Style>
  ...
</s:TitleWindow>
```

Then in the creation:

```
PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,MyPopUp, true); // modal overlay is red
```